# HibernateEnvers doesn't store current lastmodifieddate in audit table while performing delete operation

Tags: spring, hibernate-envers

I need some help in resolving this issue. The issue is:

I am using HibernateEnvers for Auditing in spring data jpa. For insert and update operations the code is working fine. But in case of delete operation, current lastmodifieddate is not logging. The lastmodified date which is getting logged is of previous operation and not the current system date. I have set this hibernate property

org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete = true

I have tried using @PostRemove and @PreRemove annotated methods to modify lastModifiedDate in entity but it doesn't work.

Please suggest some pointers on this.

Comment: What `lastmodifieddate` are you referring to?

Comment: Are you referring the REVEND_TSTMP field used in conjunction with the ValidityAuditStrategy or some other timestamp field?

Comment: Seems similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833298/hibernate-envers-how-to-capture-who-deleted-an-entity-in-audit-table